# What does the isDomain property of nsICookie mean?

Tags: firefox, cookies, firefox-addon, mozilla, xpcom

Can anybody give me a further explanation about the [`isDomain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsICookie#Attributes) property of the `nsICookie` interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `.isDomain` is true, the cookie is to be used for the whole domain (host + all subdomains), otherwise it is only to be used for a specific host.

When setting the cookie and specifying a `domain=` value with a leading `.`, the cookie becomes a domain cookie. See the [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie#Specification) documentation.

E.g.

- `domain=.example.org` will be a domain cookie (`.isDomain == true`) and will be used for `example.org` and all sub-domains, such as `www.example.org`.
- `domain=example.org` will not be a domain cookie (`.isDomain == false`) and will only be used for `example.org`, but not for subdomains.
- `domain=www.example.org` will not be a domain cookie (`.isDomain == false`) and will only be used for `www.example.org`, but not for subdomains.

It is [implemented](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/cookie/nsCookie.h#89) simply as:

```
inline bool IsDomain() const { return /* const char* */ *mHost == '.'; }
```

meaning: Return `true` if the first char of the string is a `.`, else return `false`.

Comment: So if a cookie domain is .google.com, this cookie can be used for accounts.google.com, right?

Comment: Yep, such a cookie is a domain cookie and should be transmitted to all google.com domains incl. accounts.google.com. Of course, there are other restrictions in place as well that need to be followed, such as same origin policy stuff when creating and selecting cookies. Read the RFC 2965 if in doubt.